# Unable to start development server in debug mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

When I'm starting the MobileFirst Server in debug mode, it fails loading with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MobileFirst Development Server is by default in debug mode... so when you try to start the server using the "debug mode" icon, it fails in doing so because the debug definition cannot be set twice, which is what the error message says.

To start the server in debug mode, simply start it as you would normally do it, by clicking on the "play" button.

[image]

After doing so, you can spot the following line: "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777".
This means the server started in debug mode.

Comment: i started server as u mentioned.. i got messgae stating that Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777.. thx

Comment: Idan When iam asking question iam not able to insert error image.

Comment: You do not have yet enough reputation points in stack overflow to do that; read the website's help section. You can put just link to the image for the time being.

Comment: how can i link image to my local compuetr

Comment: Dude... this is basic stuff - you can only **upload** an image! You **can't** link to a local image in your computer. You can upload an image either from your computer, or from a URL. Go read the website's help section.

Comment: Idan I have i doubt. can i clean browser cache using java/javascript/jquery when user login into application.. becoz we are randomly updating .j files..but reflecting when user manually clean browser cache through Ctrl+Alt+del option... any idea please

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. What does this have to do with this question? If this is a new question - open a new question and properly explain your scenario.

Comment: i dnot have questions to ask.. it saying wait 4 days when click on Question Ask Link